# Flex layout issue tablets/mobiles in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

This my login page in laptop

[image]

But when it comes to tab size.It is not fitting to full height of the screen.I have tried many css properties still no use.Unable to configure that which property is overriding.

Hers is the tab-size screenshot
[image]

This my html code(login-page.component.html)

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body> 

          <div class="ylet_header">
              <p class="ylet_business">MY Business</p>
          </div>

            <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" 
                            fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="0%">

                 <div fxFlex="76%" class="left-sidebar">
                     <img id="ylet_img" src="assets\img\ylet_1.jpg">
                 </div>  
                 <div fxFlex="25%" style="background-color:pink;"  id="Login- 
                      form">
                       <p class="login" align="left">Login</p>

                         ...Login page content goes here.....

                      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                  </div>

            </div>


       </body>
    </html>
```

and the css (login-page.component.css) is like this

```
    .login {
       color: #cc00cc;
       font-size: 20px;
       margin-top: 80px;
     }
    .ylet_header {
       background-color: #990099;
       height: 45px;
       width: 100%;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
     }
   .ylet_business {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: left;
      text-indent: 5%;
      margin-top: 11px;
   }
  .left-sidebar {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
   }
 .left-sidebar img {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-left: -16px;
    background-size: cover;
   }
  .forget-sec {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .ms-TextField-field {
   margin-left: -12px !important;
   }
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
   .left-sidebar {display: none;}
   }
```

One more issue is that,I want align forget password on the bottom,fixed for every devices.

Comment: `background-size: cover;` has no effect in your example because you are using an <img> and there is no background. If you replace the <img> by <div> and set its `background-image` property to your image then it should be working fine :)
pretty much like the example here: [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my comment I meant the following as working example.

extend css with:

```
   .container {
     display: flex;
     height: 100vh;
   }

   #ylet_img {
     background-image: url(https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg);
     height: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
   }
```

slightly simplified html as I am using pure css here (no angular):

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body> 

      <div class="ylet_header">
          <p class="ylet_business">MY Business</p>
      </div>

        <div class="container" >

             <div style="flex: 0 0 75%" class="left-sidebar">
             <div id="ylet_img"></div>
             </div>  
             <div style="flex: 0 0 25%" style="background-color:pink;"  id="Login- 
                  form">
                   <p class="login" align="left">Login</p>

                     ...Login page content goes here.....

                  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
              </div>

        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps and this was the effect you wanted to achieve :)